# Read all emails from inbox after a specified date and time in java using javax.mail

Tags: jakarta-mail

Right now I am able to read all Unread emails messages using java but I need to read all emails after a specified date and time using JAVAX.Mail (ie javax.mail.jar), Please help me in retrieving all the emails using java after specified date and time (say 12 july 2013,1pm).
My code for reading mails :

```
Properties prop = System.getProperties();
prop.getProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "myGmailId@gmail.com", "mypassword");
inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.mail.Message trying to fetch messages for a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428772/javax-mail-message-trying-to-fetch-messages-for-a-given-date-range)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example taken from [javax.mail.Message trying to fetch messages for a given date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428772/javax-mail-message-trying-to-fetch-messages-for-a-given-date-range)

```
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

// We would get the bounce mails received yesterday

ReceivedDateTerm term  = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.EQ,newDate(cal.getTimeInMillis()));

Message[] messages = folder.search(term)
```

Another approach of using term could be:

```
SearchTerm olderThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.LT, someFutureDate);
SearchTerm newerThan = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, somePastDate);
SearchTerm andTerm = new AndTerm(olderThan, newerThan);
inbox.search(andTerm);
```