# How to read email received in the last hour - Java

Tags: java, email-attachments

I am using Java

Here I can read all the mail in an inbox, but I need to read just those received within the last hour.`

```
properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port",String.valueOf(port));
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
try {
    // connects to the message store
    Store store = session.getStore("pop3");
    store.connect(userName, password);
    // opens the inbox folder
    Folder folderInbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    folderInbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    Message[] arrayMessages = folderInbox.getMessages();
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayMessages.length; i++) {
        Message message = arrayMessages[i];
        Address[] fromAddress = message.getFrom();
        String from = fromAddress[0].toString();
        String subject = message.getSubject();
        String toList = parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO));
        String ccList = parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.CC));
        String bccList = parseAddresses(message.getRecipients(RecipientType.BCC));
        String sentDate = message.getSentDate().toString();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read all emails from inbox after a specified date and time in java using javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18608970/read-all-emails-from-inbox-after-a-specified-date-and-time-in-java-using-javax-m)

Answer (score 0):

Restrict the `sentDate` with desired boundaries e.g

```
if(new Date(sentDate.getTime()).compareTo(newDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3600 * 1000)) > 0) {
         //desired action
         ...
}
```